# New tax zones doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I just recently realized that some countries aren't charged tax in my webshop. I found out this was caused by the fact that some tax zones werent created.

Upon finding out, I went to Sales -> TAX -> Mange TAX zones & Rates and started setting up the correct tax rates for each country that we ship to. In this menu, I realized that all countries that are already setup are created 6 times, with the same name and settings. Why could this be?

Also, when creating a new tax rule for a country it doesn't seem to kick through. I have emptied cache and refreshed indexes multiple times, but it doesn't change anything.

Do I need to set additional settings somewhere else?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I had to add the destination in Tax -> Tax Rules for the specific destination as well.